# Will a frictionless conveyer belt run forever?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, friction

The rollers of the conveyor belt are frictionless. The belt itself has a mass $M$. A prime mover, attached to one of the rollers, accelerates the belt to some velocity $v$ such that the rollers at the ends are rotating with a angular velocity $\omega$ (no slip between the rollers and the belt). Now the prime mover is removed. Neglecting friction and air resistance, should the belt continue to rotate with the same velocity $v$ until some external force is applied?

If not, how long will it take for the belt to come to rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem that sensitively depends on how you model it. You could take a high-level perspective and say there are no dissipative forces removing energy from the system, so hence it will continue to move forever. You could note that the belt will experience periodic elastic compression/extension along the end rollers, and that this will be dissipative (turning motion into thermal energy at some rate), making it stop eventually.

In short, there is no single answer to the question without specifying it better or stating the assumptions used to get to the answer.

Comment: You also cannot use it to move things.